# How to create "Date" containers in Matlab, ignoring months and years?

Tags: matlab, date, binary, containers, extract

My goal is to extract specific rows from a table (see below) that fall into specific "date" containers, e.g. month-end (**25th-31st, regardless of the month and year**). Date range from Jan-2005 until Aug-2016 and time-step is "weekly".

[image]

So far I only managed to create binaries for rows that fall into a *specific* date period:

```
% T.Date=[datetime(T.Date, 'InputFormat', 'eee dd-MMM-yyyy')];
% Define date containers
  tlower = datetime(2016,07,25);
  tupper = datetime(2016,07,31); 
% Return ones if date falls in between tlower and tupper 
  Binary = isbetween(T.Date,tlower,tupper)
% If "Binary" returns 1, use this row and stack it into a new table 
% with same headers as table "T". -> How?
```

How can I create date containers that ignore months and years, returning all rows in a new table that are "month-end" (25th-31st of each month) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the [`datetime` class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime-properties.html), you will see there is a `Day` property that you can use to create your mask.

For example:

```
% Generate sample data
dates = datetime(2014,6,28) + calweeks(0:9);
randomdata = rand(1,10);
T = table(dates', randomdata', 'VariableNames', {'Dates', 'Data'})

% Mask and build new table
mask = T.Dates.Day >= 25 & T.Dates.Day <= 31;
newT = T(mask, :)
```

Gives us an original table `T`:

```
T = 

       Dates        Data  
    ___________    _______

    28-Jun-2014    0.55337
    05-Jul-2014    0.92311
    12-Jul-2014    0.99922
    19-Jul-2014    0.16673
    26-Jul-2014    0.29107
    02-Aug-2014    0.86206
    09-Aug-2014    0.88442
    16-Aug-2014    0.71856
    23-Aug-2014    0.89521
    30-Aug-2014    0.21284
```

And a masked table `newT`:

```
newT = 

       Dates        Data  
    ___________    _______

    28-Jun-2014    0.55337
    26-Jul-2014    0.29107
    30-Aug-2014    0.21284
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @excaza! This is exactly what I was intending to do, very much appreciated